# redirect external link reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I tried it in a few ways, but every time the url looks like this: http://localhost:3000/www.google.com

I tried with:

```
<a href="www.google.com" ><Title>Go to Google</Title></a>
```

I also tried with:

```
function goToGoogle(){
    return window.location.href = "www.google.com"
}

<Title as="h5" appearance="primary" className=".teste" onClick={goToGoogle} >Go to Google</Title>
```

My routes:

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader show fullScreen />}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={PAGE.ROOT()} component={LazyLogin} />
        <Route exact path="/password" component={LazyPassword} />
        <Route exact path="/block" component={LazyBlock} />
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
```